# How to show advanced search in custom.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, search, advanced-search

i am try to call advanced search in custom.phtml

`<?php   echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalogsearch/advanced_form')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml')->toHtml()  ?>`

like this when i try to search it goes to

`http://127.0.0.1/magento-19/index.php/cms/index/result/?name=saf&description=&short_description=&sku=&price%5Bfrom%5D=&price%5Bto%5D=&type_cartridge=&merk=&eancode=`

if i mannually add ***catalogsearch/advanced*** instead ***cms/index*** it shows me fine.

Pst: custom.phtml directly shows through cms/page

`<p>{{block type="categorydrop/navigation" template="categorydrop/custom.phtml"}}</p>`

so, how can i use advanced search in custom.phtml ?

also my default search is not working? i want to work as autosearch but its not show me result?

i use `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(‘topSearch’) ?>` this in custom.phtml for use default search its not show me.

Thanks in advanced...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get that strange url because of the method `getSearchPostUrl` in the advanced search form class. It looks like this:

```
public function getSearchPostUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/result');
}
```

This means that the url where the search form will be sent is `{current_module}/{current_controller}/result`.
You have to options here.

1. Clone `catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml` into an other template file, use that for rendering the block and change inside it:

   `<form action="<?php echo $this->getSearchPostUrl() ?>" method="get" id="form-validate">` to `<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result') ?>" method="get" id="form-validate">`
2. Create a new block class that extends `Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form`, use that for your homepage, and change the `getSearchPostUrl` to return `$this->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result')`.

I would go with option 1. Less work.

Comment: yeah it works. thanks bro...
but i just try little different way i mean i create one textbox and button and on click of button ajax call and pass that parameter to that url. plz see is it correct ? its in below comment

Comment: `<button type="button"  class="button btn-cart" onclick="searchProduct();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></span></span></button>`



`function searchProduct(){
 //alert("ad");
 new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->getUrl("catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=") ?>', {
  method: 'get',
  //parameters: Form.serialize("form-validate"),
  onComplete: function(transport) {
   
            }
 });
}`

Comment: How to pass value from textbox?

Comment: I think this is a totally different question. Don't mix them.

Comment: it's done. Thank you!!!
i use 
`var nam = document.getElementById("search_cartridge").value;
window.location="<?php echo $this->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result/') ?>"+"?name="+nam;`
it also redirect to that page